# HP P400 and Sata disk

Tags: raid, hard-drive, storage, hp, hp-proliant

I have an old HP ML110 server with OEM windows Server license that I have to use for a few more months. Internal raid controller is causing me some problems so I want to buy another hardware controller, connect 2 hard disk to raid 1 and install Windows.
I found that old HP p400 controller are quite cheap and thinking of using one.
Will this controller work with "SFF-8484 to 4 x SATA" cable and two 500GB SATA ( non HP ) hdd drivers ?

http://www.ebay.com/itm/441823-001-HP-Smart-Array-P400-Dual-Internal-SAS-PCI-E2-0X8-SP-Raid-Controller-/271585117501?hash=item3f3bbc053d:g:wZEAAOSw4GVYRblg
and
http://www.ebay.com/itm/1M-SAS-32pin-SFF-8484-to-4-x-SATA-7Pin-Male-Hard-Disk-Drive-Red-Cable-/281410542917?hash=item4185601d45:g:fywAAOSwQItT4EvA

Comment: Which exact 'Gen' have you got?

Comment: Old - G3, for my purpose right now is ok, I am pretty sure that controller will work with motherboard but i have doubts about sata hard drives

Comment: Ok, well it's not a supported combination but I'm 99% sure it will work

Answer (score 0):

A SATA disk connected to the Smart Array P400 controller will downshift to 1.5Gbps speeds instead of 3Gbps or 6Gbps.

I would not recommend this.